# How to install a theme with the command line?

Tags: drush, 9, installation

I am trying to install the theme [Adaptivetheme](https://www.drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme).

I have tried this

```shell
composer require drupal/adaptivetheme
```

and then:

```shell
vendor/bin/drush theme:enable adaptivetheme
```

But I got:

> Unknown themes: adaptivetheme.

How to install a theme with the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation. The only provided theme in the package is at_core but its description is:

> Base theme only - do not set to default. Use the AT Theme Generator to generate or clone a theme to get started.